# Как сделать выполнение условия по статусу запроса?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, валидация, response

Есть кастомный notification который срабатывает на submit. Но проблема в том, что он выдает диалоговое окно вне зависимости от того прошел запрос валидацию или нет. Хочу сделать условие через код статуса самого запроса, но не понимаю как к нему обратиться.

вот сам Vue компонент

```
<template>
    <div>

        <notifications classes="notification-edit" group="foo" />

        <form @submit.prevent="submit">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="task-title">Task name</label>
                    <input v-model="task.title"
                           type="text"
                           name="title"
                           class="form-control"
                           id="task-title">
                    <div class="text-danger pt-1" v-show="errors.title">{{errors.title}}</div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="task-description">Task description</label>
                    <textarea name="description"
                              class="form-control"
                              id="task-description"
                              rows="3"
                              v-model="task.description"></textarea>
                    <div class="text-danger pt-1" v-show="errors.description">{{errors.description}}</div>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update task</button>
        </form>

    </div>
</template>


<script>

    export default {

        props: [
            'oldtask'
        ],

        data() {
            return {
                task: {
                    id: '',
                    title: '',
                    description: ''
                },
                errors: {
                    title: '',
                    description: ''
                },
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            this.getDate();
        },

        methods: {

            getDate() {
                this.task = this.oldtask;
            },

            submit() {
                this.errors.title = ''
                this.errors.description = ''
                axios
                    .patch(`/api/tasks/`+this.task.id, {
                    id: this.oldtask.id,
                    title: this.task.title,
                    description: this.task.description
                    })
                    .then(response => {
                        window.location.href = `/`;

                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        if (error.response.status === 422) {
                            console.log(error.response.data.errors);
                            this.errors.title = error.response.data.errors.title[0]
                            this.errors.description = error.response.data.errors.description[0]
                        }
                    })

                    //кастомный notification
                    this.$notify({
                        group: 'foo',
                        title: 'Hello user!',
                        text: 'Ты отредактировал таску!'
                    })
                },

            },

        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так ведь у тебя `this.$notify()` вызывается за пределами хуков `then` и `catch` промиса! То есть уведомление всплывает даже раньше, чем сервер ответит. Чтобы это исправить, помести вызов `this.$notify()` в обработчик нужного тебе хука:

```
axios.patch(`/api/tasks/`+this.task.id, {
  id: this.oldtask.id,
  title: this.task.title,
  description: this.task.description
})
  .then(response => {
    // Вставить this.$notify() сюда 
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // И/или сюда
  })
```

Comment: да я так и понял уже)), спасибо что ответили.

Comment: Ну, всегда рад!)